# onclick not working when removing/appending child element

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I have a simple *.svg file with some javascript code inside.
There are 6 circles and they partially overlay each other.
When a mousover event occurs for one of the circle, this circle should appear at the top.
This works just fine. Here is my code:

```
 <svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="400" height="300">

    <script>
            function mouseOver(evt) {
                var parent = evt.target.parentNode;
                parent.removeChild(evt.target);
                parent.appendChild(evt.target);
            }

            function click(evt) {
                alert("CLICKED");
            }
    </script>

<g id="myCircles" stroke="none" onclick="click(evt)" onmouseover="mouseOver(evt)">
    <circle id="circ1" cx="150" cy="100" r="50" fill="red"/>
    <circle id="circ2" cx="100" cy="60" r="30" fill="yellow"/>
    <circle id="circ3" cx="200" cy="150" r="80" fill="blue"/>
    <circle id="circ4" cx="160" cy="190" r="70" fill="green"/>
    <circle id="circ5" cx="100" cy="220" r="10" fill="gray"/>
    <circle id="circ6" cx="80" cy="90" r="20" fill="black"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

However if I use this `mouseOver` function the `onclick` event doesn't work anymore. I guess this has something to do with the removing and appinding of the Element inside the `DOM` structure.
If i uncomment the code in `mouseOver(evt)`, the onclick event gets fired.
Anyone knows how to solve this?

**EDIT**: Interestingly, when I am using `onmousedown` instead of `onclick` event, everything works fine! Can anybody explain why?

Comment: I am guess u ment if u comment the stuff in the mouseOver?

Comment: You know when you fire your function and then remove the child, the event handler is also removed. Meaning, you hav no click event and mouse over events. You have to add them back.

Comment: Firstly the handlers are on the parent so removing children won't affect them. Secondly the event handlers if they were on the children would be reinstated when the element is readded (modulo UA bugs of course).

Comment: The next thing I noticed is that this behavior only occurs in Internet Explorer...

Answer (score -1):

You could use the z-index property to bring the selected circle to the top. If you use a .css file, add the z-index and set the initial value to the same value (say, '1')

```
 z-index:1;
```

on the mouseover event, change the z-index to a higher value (say, '5') to pop it to the top of the circle stack. on the mouseout event, reset z-index to 1 and, finally, use the mousedown event to produce your alert, "Clicked."

Comment: SVG doesn't have a z-index property. It's proposed for SVG 2 but I'm not sure anything implements that part of SVG 2 yet.